# Fail to start distributed LocalCluster in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, distributed

I have problems with using distributed's LocalCluster and tried to generate a minimal example. But I even fail to do that (I am using python 3.6, distributed 1.23.3, tornado 5.1.1). If I create a python file `test.py` with the content:

```
from distributed import LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster()
```

and execute the file with:

```
python test.py
```

I get very lengthy error message:

```
...
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 841 was killed by unknown signal
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
tornado.application - ERROR - Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 217, in _start_worker
    raise gen.TimeoutError("Worker failed to start")
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.start(ip=ip, n_workers=n_workers)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 171, in start
    self.sync(self._start, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 164, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 277, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 262, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 191, in _start
    yield [self._start_worker(**self.worker_kwargs) for i in range(n_workers)]
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 217, in _start_worker
    raise gen.TimeoutError("Worker failed to start")
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
distributed.process - WARNING - reaping stray process <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerProcess-10, started daemon)>
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 849 was killed by unknown signal
/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py:143: UserWarning: semaphore_tracker: There appear to be 12 leaked semaphores to clean up at shutdown
  len(cache))
Exception ignored in: <bound method LocalCluster.__del__ of LocalCluster('tcp://127.0.0.1:38903', workers=0, ncores=0)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 340, in __del__
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 291, in close
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 427, in run_sync
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 272, in sync
tornado.util.TimeoutError: timed out after 20 s.
```

The strange thing is if I just open a python shell and type in the two lines everything works as expected.

**Update:**

putting everything in a function works:

```
from distributed import LocalCluster

def main():
    cluster = LocalCluster()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

still confused why the first version fails.